# None of the edit is approved in last 2 days

Tags: support, suggested-edits

From last 2 days I have edited almost 30-35 question but none of them is being approved.
Is there a limit on edit or any other reasons Why my edits are not being accepted.

Comment: They have been approved, just that you've reached the 1000 rep limit from suggested edits.

Comment: So I will not be awarded points here onwards for the edits I do.

Comment: That's right. You can see the review results under your account by pressing activity / suggestions on your SO profile and clicking the suggested edit link.

Comment: You can check what happened to your suggested edits in your [activity](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2958035/jatin?tab=activity) tab in your profile.

Comment: Thanks Guys :) so only 1000 edits :)

Comment: But its say 599 suggestions..????

Comment: +2 rep per suggested edit. So, you stopped accumulating rep after 500 edits.

Comment: @Jatin You're still allowed to suggest edits - this just means you've suggested 599 edits. You've only gained reputation for the first 500 that were accepted, however.

Comment: Ohh I see... so I get reputation till 1000. After that I am allowed to edit but no reputations. I got it. But is there any particular reason for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), reputation from suggested edits maxes out at 1,000 rep.

You have suggested (and got approved) upwards of 500 edits (at +2 apiece), as shown by [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4487128) (2K+). In fact, you have 571 approved edits at the time of this writing. You stopped earning rep from edits once the 500th suggested edit became approved.

Community Wiki from [Qantas 94 Heavy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228752/none-of-the-edit-is-approved-in-last-2-days#comment750185_228752) and [Michael Petrotta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228752/none-of-the-edit-is-approved-in-last-2-days#comment750198_228752).

Comment: I got that now. But is there any particular reasons to award just 1000 reputations only.

Comment: @Jatin Yes. That reason is that users need to also demonstrate programming knowledge to be trusted on SO. By just making good edits, we can't tell if you are good at edits or good at programming. And because rep is a measurement of how much the community trusts you, it's a little unfair to say that someone has programming skills if they are actually only good at editing. We then decided to cut edit rep off at 1000.

Comment: Thanks Blue Ice... thats what I was looking for.